# how to replace one sentence to another one for many files

Tags: bash, unix

I have over 2000 files with the format of .txt the first line of these files are written "PUT KEYWORDS HERE" I want to automatically replace them with "my files 1000X with XYT of 20gt"

how can I do this? I am using terminal in Mac

```
bash-3.2$
```

I am trying to do it like this

at first I find how many files I have in the folder

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

then I tried

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -I
```

but I don't know how to set it to replace

I also tried

```
for file in *.txt; do sed -i '1s/.*/PUT KEYWORDS HERE/' "$my files 1000X with XYT of 20gt"; done
```

Comment: You really do not want to attempt to use `sed -i` or any other tool to do the replacements in the files.  You risk corrupting and/or losing data.  Disk is cheap.  Filter the files into a new directory.

Comment: @William Pursell
give me a better solution please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to edit files "in-place".  Especially if you are doing a bulk modification on many files.  There is too much risk of corrupting and/or losing data.  Change the files into a new directory.  eg, if your files are in a directory named `data`:

```
$ mkdir new
$ for i in data/*; do sed -e '1s/.*/my files 1000X with XYT of 20gt/' "$i" > "new${i#data}"; done
```

After you verify that the new data (now in the directory named "new") is what you want, you can delete the old data (`rm -rf data`), and `mv new old` if you need to retain the original paths.

Even if you don't do rigorous verification of the new data, this is safer than trying to edit in-place.  For example, if the process is half way done and you lose power, it is much more difficult to pick up where you left off since you won't easily know which files have been changed.  Issue like this are mitigated by creating a new directory.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
sed -i '' 's/PUT KEYWORDS HERE/my files 1000X with XYT of 20gt/' *.txt
```